# How to trigger an event on slider picture change in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a slider in project.when slider img change event should be triggerd i tried on classChange Event but nothing happens

**link of my code**

```
 [1] https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gzLYaO
```

Comment: There is no such thing as `classChange` event.

Comment: Also it isn't the `li` -list item with the changing class. It's a `div` with the a `class` of **item**

Comment: $('.carousel-indicators li').on('classChange', function() {});
i tried this

Comment: @NewToJS what should i do?

Comment: @dani Maybe this example will be of some use to you [**CodePen Example**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BxQBdL)

Comment: @NewToJS thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap 3 Carousel:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myCarousel").on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
        alert('Slide change');
    });
});
```

`slid.bs.carousel` event occurs when the carousel has finished sliding from one item to another.

`slide.bs.carousel` event occurs when the carousel is about to slide from one item to another.